# List of substitutions in external file

Tags: ruby, string, csv, substitution

I need to pass a string against an external file that contains a list of substitutions to perform at every occurrence.

The substitution file will look like this (I'm open to suggestions on the structure, it can be a csv, a yaml, etc...)

```
"ipsum" "foobar"
"elit" ""
"sit amet" "2312"
```

My ruby code should be implemented like this:

```
mystring = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis elit augue. Nulla tempus magna nec ligula dapibus malesuada. Fusce at orci augue, sit amet suscipit sem. Suspendisse potenti."

newstring = mystring.somemagichappenshere
```

And the newstring value should be `"Lorem foobar dolor 2312, consectetur adipiscing . Aliquam quis  augue. Nulla tempus magna nec ligula dapibus malesuada. Fusce at orci augue, 2312 suscipit sem. Suspendisse potenti."`

How should I implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a csv:

```
require 'csv'
str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis elit augue. Nulla tempus magna nec ligula dapibus malesuada. Fusce at orci augue, sit amet suscipit sem. Suspendisse potenti."

replacements = "ipsum,foobar
elit,
sit amet,2312"
#construct a hash from the csv:
transform_table = Hash[CSV.parse(replacements)]
#Take the keys from the hash and use them for a regular expression:
re = Regexp.union(transform_table.keys)
#Do all substituions in one go:
p str.gsub(re, transform_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple

1. Read the file
2. Iterate each line in the file and for each entry use `mystring.gsub!(find, replace)` to replace the value with the substitution

Comment: It’ll fail when the latter keyword matches the previous value.